# How do I connect the UI of a game with the gameloop in JavaFx

Tags: javafx

I am a beginner. I am making a simple 2D game using JavaFx. I have the code of the basic game-loop. Now I want to make a complete game where I can open a starting window which has new game, settings etc options... also I want to add different levels and game score and game over message... how can I do that? I can make simple UI window. But I am having problem in starting and closing the game using it. i am completely messed up... need help now :(

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ColorRun extends Application {

private static final double KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA = 5;
private static final double RECT_WIDTH = 200;
private static final double RECT_HEIGHT = 70;
private static final double RECT_MAX_Y = 800;

private static Rectangle createRectangle(double x) {
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, 0, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
rect.setArcWidth(10);
rect.setArcHeight(10);
return rect;
}

private final Random random = new Random();

private void randomizeColors(Rectangle[] rects, Circle circle, List<Color> 
colors) {
Collections.shuffle(colors, random);
for (int i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    rects[i].setFill(colors.get(i));
}
circle.setFill(colors.get(random.nextInt(colors.size())));
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, 
Color.YELLOW, Color.GREY);

Circle circle = new Circle(650, 700, 20);
Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[5];
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
    rectangles[i] = createRectangle(RECT_WIDTH * i);
}

Pane root = new Pane();
root.setPrefHeight(RECT_MAX_Y);
for (Rectangle rect : rectangles) {
    root.getChildren().add(rect);
}
root.getChildren().add(circle);

final double frameDuration = 16;
final double iterationDuration = 4000;
final int framesPerIteration = (int) (iterationDuration / frameDuration + 1);
randomizeColors(rectangles, circle, colors);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

class FrameHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    KeyCode code;
    private int frame = 1;

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (frame == 0) {
            randomizeColors(rectangles, circle, colors); // change colors 
when iteration is done
        }

        // move circle, if key is pressed
        if (code != null) {
            switch (code) {
                case RIGHT:
                    circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + 
KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() - 
KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // move rects & check intersection
        final Paint color = circle.getFill();
        final double cx = circle.getCenterX();
        final double cy = circle.getCenterY();
        final double r2 = circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius();
        boolean lost = false;
        for (Rectangle rect : rectangles) {
            rect.setY(frame * RECT_MAX_Y / framesPerIteration);
            // check for intersections with rects of wrong color
            if (rect.getFill() != color) {

                double dy = Math.min(Math.abs(rect.getY() - cy),
                        Math.abs(rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() - cy));
                dy = dy * dy;

                if (dy > r2) {
                    continue; // y-distance too great for intersection
                }
                if (cx >= rect.getX() && cx <= rect.getX() + rect.getWidth()) 
{
                    lost = true;
                } else {
                    double dx = Math.min(Math.abs(rect.getX() - cx),
                            Math.abs(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() - cx));
                    if (dx * dx + dy <= r2) {
                        lost = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        frame = (frame + 1) % framesPerIteration;
        if (lost) {
            timeline.stop();
        }

    }
}

FrameHandler frameHandler = new FrameHandler();

Scene scene = new Scene(root);

// keep track of the state of the arrow keys
scene.setOnKeyPressed(evt -> {
    KeyCode code = evt.getCode();
    switch (code) {
        case RIGHT:
        case LEFT:
            frameHandler.code = code;
            break;
    }
});
scene.setOnKeyReleased(evt -> {
    KeyCode code = evt.getCode();
    if (frameHandler.code == code) {
        frameHandler.code = null;
    }
});

primaryStage.setScene(scene);

timeline.getKeyFrames()
        .add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(frameDuration), frameHandler));
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

timeline.play();

primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am afraid this is far too broad of a question for SO. You will want to narrow it down to a specific question (ie: How do I display a window using JavaFX?). However, you should also first search SO for your question, as most beginner questions have already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

So I tested the application(was very cool for a starter app) figured I would set up some buttons to help get you started you should check out some tutorials about more advanced games I would pay attention to how they(in tutorials) setup their main screens among other things and your question is way to broad to answer but I didn't want you to get discouraged and stop coding.  When you come to stack overflow try to come up with an exact question of what went wrong other than i can't start and close the game try to do some problem solving of you own google around for code examples and see what others did and how they solved it or how did the tutorials do it .Also look around google some things about starter game apps and you will soon realize that this can be structured much better I did not intend for these buttons to look good but only to function goodluck and happy coding

PS my comments are inside of what I added

```
private static final double KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA = 5;
private static final double RECT_WIDTH = 200;
private static final double RECT_HEIGHT = 70;
private static final double RECT_MAX_Y = 800;

private static Rectangle createRectangle(double x) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, 0, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
    rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rect.setArcWidth(10);
    rect.setArcHeight(10);
    return rect;
}

private final Random random = new Random();

private void randomizeColors(Rectangle[] rects, Circle circle, List<Color> colors) {
    Collections.shuffle(colors, random);
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        rects[i].setFill(colors.get(i));
    }
    circle.setFill(colors.get(random.nextInt(colors.size())));
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREY);

    Circle circle = new Circle(650, 700, 20);
    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        rectangles[i] = createRectangle(RECT_WIDTH * i);
    }

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefHeight(RECT_MAX_Y);
    for (Rectangle rect : rectangles) {
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
    root.getChildren().add(circle);

//Here is where I added 2 buttons
    //Added Restart Button
    Button restartButton = new Button("Restart");
    restartButton.setVisible(false); //set to false so you cannot see them when playing
    //Added Quit button
    Button quitButton = new Button("Quit");
    quitButton.setVisible(false);
    restartButton.setLayoutY(30);

    final double frameDuration = 16;
    final double iterationDuration = 4000;
    final int framesPerIteration = (int) (iterationDuration / frameDuration + 1);
    randomizeColors(rectangles, circle, colors);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    class FrameHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        private KeyCode code;
        private int frame = 1;
        public boolean lost = false;
//Here I created a lost action which will run when you lose
        private void lostAction(){
            timeline.stop();
            restartButton.setVisible(true);
            quitButton.setVisible(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (frame == 0) {
                randomizeColors(rectangles, circle, colors); // change colors when iteration is done
            }

            // move circle, if key is pressed
            if (code != null) {
                switch (code) {
                    case RIGHT:
                        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() +
                                KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() -
                                KEYBOARD_MOVEMENT_DELTA);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // move rects & check intersection
            final Paint color = circle.getFill();
            final double cx = circle.getCenterX();
            final double cy = circle.getCenterY();
            final double r2 = circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius();
            for (Rectangle rect : rectangles) {
                rect.setY(frame * RECT_MAX_Y / framesPerIteration);
                // check for intersections with rects of wrong color
                if (rect.getFill() != color) {

                    double dy = Math.min(Math.abs(rect.getY() - cy),
                            Math.abs(rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() - cy));
                    dy = dy * dy;

                    if (dy > r2) {
                        continue; // y-distance too great for intersection
                    }
                    if (cx >= rect.getX() && cx <= rect.getX() + rect.getWidth())
                    {
                        lost = true;
                    } else {
                        double dx = Math.min(Math.abs(rect.getX() - cx),
                                Math.abs(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() - cx));
                        if (dx * dx + dy <= r2) {
                            lost = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            frame = (frame + 1) % framesPerIteration;
            if (lost) {
                lostAction();//This was altered to point at lost function
            }
        }
    }

    FrameHandler frameHandler = new FrameHandler();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);// keep track of the state of the arrow keys
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(evt -> {
        KeyCode code = evt.getCode();
        switch (code) {
            case RIGHT:
            case LEFT:
                frameHandler.code = code;
                break;
        }
    });
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(evt -> {
        KeyCode code = evt.getCode();
        if (frameHandler.code == code) {
            frameHandler.code = null;
        }
    });
//Here is where I added the actions of the buttons
    //Resets variables in order to keep playing
    restartButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        frameHandler.lost = !frameHandler.lost;
        frameHandler.frame=0;
        timeline.play();
        restartButton.setVisible(false);
        quitButton.setVisible(false);
    });
    //This will let you leave without it you will play forever
    quitButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.exit(0);
    });
    root.getChildren().addAll(restartButton, quitButton);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(frameDuration), frameHandler));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    primaryStage.show();
}
```